# Does Microsoft chatbot(Node.js and C#) support WeChat integration in Chinese and English?

Tags: c#, node.js, chatbot, wechat

I have a chatbot which is built in Microsoft bot framework with Node.js and I integrated this bot with a NLP framework called LUIS.AI as well. I am integrating it with Skype and Messenger and also trying to integrate it with WeChat. I am trying to use following link for WeChat integration but not yet able to do it.
https://github.com/jyfcrw/botbuilder-wechat-connector and https://github.com/markusf/botbuilder-wechat
Is there any other documentation or example for WeChat channel integration?

Comment: hi yadavr,
I hope you might have integrated ms chatbot with wechat. I have similar requirement , can you please help me with the steps for integrating ms chatbot with wechat.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research i found that we can use DirectLine3.0 to connect to the WeChat backend. There is not an official channel yet.﻿
Here are some useful links:
http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/16/Calling-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework-Using-The-Direct-Line-API

https://github.com/leonlj/BotDemo

Comment: hi yadavr, i above link you it is showing how to develop bot, my bot is ready and it is published in Azure. Now from Azure how i can publish it to wechat. can you please help me with the steps.

Answer (score 0):

I had just published a BotBulider Connector that supports Wechat **PERSONAL** Account at here:

- GitHub: https://github.com/zixia/botbuilder-wechaty-connector
- NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-wechaty-connector

It will be easy to use because you only need to scan the QR code to log in instead of register an official account with APP_ID & APP_SECRET.

#### Code Example

```
import * as builder         from 'botbuilder'
import { WechatyConnector } from 'botbuilder-wechaty-connector'

// Create wechat personal account connector
const wechatyConnector = new WechatyConnector()

const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(wechatyConnector)

bot.dialog('/', [/* ... */])

wechatyConnector.listen()
```

#### See More

In case you are interesting more, here's a blog post I had just wrote: [Integrate Wechat Personal Account to Microsoft BotFramework with a BotBuilder Wechaty Connector](https://blog.chatie.io/botbuilder-wechaty-connector/)